# R function which.max with tapply

Tags: r, dataframe, tapply

I am trying to make a data frame with the maximum over records by a factor. I would like a data frame with 4 rows (one for each G) with the max for X in that group and the corresponding Y value. I know I could write a loop but would rather not.

```
Data<-data.frame(X=rnorm(200), Y=rnorm(200), G=rep(c(1,2,3,4), each=50))
XMax<-tapply(Data$X, Data$G, function(x){max(x, na.rm=T)})
WhichXMax<-tapply(Data$X, Data$G, function(x){which.max(x)})
```

The which.max function returns the row number after the data has been subsetted by the tapply factor, where I really want the row number referencing the Data rows. So I could do something like;

```
YMax<-Data$Y[Which]
MaxData<-data.frame(XMax=XMax, YMax=YMax, G=levels(Data$G))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `by` and reference the `rownames` of the row returned by `which.max`:

```
Data[by(Data, Data$G, function(dat) rownames(dat)[which.max(dat$X)] ),]

#           X          Y G
#4   1.595281 -0.3309078 1
#61  2.401618  0.9510128 2
#147 2.087167  0.9160193 3
#171 2.307978 -0.3887222 4
```

(This assumes  `set.seed(1)` for reproducibility's sake)

Answer (score 7):

```
library(dplyr)
Data %>% 
    group_by(G) %>% 
    filter(X==max(X))
```

If you don't want to include ties, then

```
Data %>%
    group_by(G) %>%
    arrange(desc(X)) %>%
    slice(1)
```

Comment: I have tried this code on my 'real data' and it gives me 6 more rows than there are in length(levels(Data$G)) any ideas? It looks like it reports both rows if there is a tie? Whereas the accepted answer just chooses one for the tie. Also could you please explain the operation %<%, I have not seen that one before! :)

Answer (score 5):

```
  library(data.table)
  set.seed(1)
  Data<-data.frame(X=rnorm(200), Y=rnorm(200), G=rep(c(1,2,3,4), each=50))
  setDT(Data)[,list(X=max(X),Y=Y[which.max(X)]),by=G]
   G        X          Y
1: 1 1.595281 -0.3309078
2: 2 2.401618  0.9510128
3: 3 2.087167  0.9160193
4: 4 2.307978 -0.3887222
```

Comment: Simpler: `setDT(Data)[,.SD[which.max(X)],by=G]`